# convert image to canvas in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas

How I can convert image (img.jpg) to canvas in windows phone  c#

Comment: What about [punctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation)? It would help to make your question understandable.

Comment: See that agin I am edited it

Comment: You would have to be a lot more specific about what you actually want to do. Perhaps add an Image control to a Canvas? Hard to tell.